# What typically happens when two or more professors from the same department want the same prospective PhD student?

Tags: phd, advisor, professorship

If a talented PhD applicant names (in their statement of purpose) two or three professors at a department that they'd like to work with, and this student is accepted by the department, with all of the named professors equally desiring to hire this student into their respective research groups, then what lands up happening, typically?

A coin toss?

Give the student to an academically younger prof.?

Comment: What about "student chooses"?

Comment: Or they go into the courtyard and sort it out like in the good old times - whoever integrates faster, gets the student... ;-)

Comment: Barter Town has the answer. "Two profs enter! One prof leaves!"

Comment: This is not usual, but in one economics department I know, the professors make closed bids for the right to choose a grad student first. So basically the one with the largest willingness (which is of course related to ability) to pay gets the student. But actually the student can work with both on the dissertation.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you would ultimately have the final choice in the matter. The supervisor is somebody that you have to work with for 4+ years, so you better make sure you choose the one you think you can handle for that period of time.

Comment: But how will you decide that you can handle someone who you don't know for that duration? Most of the times, things are superficial and poorly perceived.

Comment: In our system, its like getting a job. If two profs have jobs to offer, then the student decides which offer to take.

Comment: @Coder Heh heh. You go on dates with the profs, like "The Bachelor."

Comment: @Coder You should reach out to former students of each supervisor, that is one of the best ways you can find out what type of professor you would be dealing with. Profs usually have a section of their CV in which they list past PhD students, a quick Google search will let you figure out if you have the right person, then you establish the communication.